# Переменная не принимает новое значение

Tags: python, python-3.x

До последнего не хотел сюда писать, но, видимо, придется.
Буквально день назад начал изучать питон, решил написать простую игру аля "Орел-Решка", но с системой начисления (или снятия) очков. Сделал так, чтобы при введении большего значения для ставки, нежели имеется на балансе, код просил повторно ввести уже корректное значение для ставки. Однако даже если ввести нормальное значение, старое никуда не пропадает, и в случае победы или поражения начисляется (либо соответственно снимается) количество очков, равное "некорректной" ставке. Не знаю как исправить:

```
import random2

balance = 100

running = True
while running:
    print('Ваш баланс:', balance, 'очков. \nВведите вашу ставку:')

    stavka = int(input()) #ставка

    def no_funds(): #функция, срабатывающая, если значение ставки выше значения баланса
        stavka = int(input()) #повторный ввод "нормальной" ставки
        if stavka <= balance:
            print('Ваша ставка: ', str(stavka), 'очков(а)') #здесь выводится уже новое значение ставки, однако на стадии начисления или снятия очков переменная снова принимает старое (первое) значение
        else:
            print('Недостаточно средств')
            print('Введите корректное число:')
            no_funds() #если ставка опять выше, функция еще раз повторяется

    if stavka <= balance:
        print('Ваша ставка:', str(stavka), 'очков(а)')
    else:
        print('Недостаточно средств')
        print('Введите корректное число:')
        no_funds()


    a = random2.randint(1, 3) % 2

    choice = input('Что выпадет: Орёл (введите "1") или Решка (введите"2")?\n')

    if choice == 1: #если выпал орёл
        if a == 1:
            print('Выпал Орёл, Вы выиграли!')
            balance = balance + stavka
        else:
            print('Выпала Решка, Вы проиграли!')
            balance = balance - stavka
    else: #если выпала решка
        if a == 0:
            print('Выпала Решка, Вы выиграли!')
            balance = balance + stavka
        else:
            print('Выпал Орёл, Вы проиграли!')
            balance = balance - stavka

    print('Ваш новый баланс:', balance, 'очков')

    if balance == 1000:
        print('Ты абсолютный победитель, нет смысла играть дальше!')

    yes_no = input('Сыграть снова?\n')

    if yes_no == 'да' or yes_no == 'Да':
        running = True
    else:
        print('Хорошо поиграли. Увидимся!')
        running = False
```

Возможны некоторые ошибки оформления кода, приму критику с удовольствием.

Comment: Вы изменяете локальную переменную `stavka` внутри функции `no_funds`, а чтобы изменить внешнюю переменную снаружи функции, нужно внутри функции дописать строчку `nonlocal stavka`

Comment: И с балансом кстати то же самое

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо большое. Изучил тему, все поправил, заработало)

Comment: вместо строки  if yes_no == 'да' or yes_no == 'Да': лучше использовать if yes_no.lower() =='Да':, так вы будете переводить строку в нижний регистр, а в вашем случае ваша программа не сработает на 'ДА' или 'Да', это не критично но вы сами сказали что примите критику)

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто необходимо объявить переменную `stavka` глобальной, чтобы ее спокойно можно было изменять вне функции, так же у вас нет условия окончания, то есть если ваш баланс будет 0 ваша программа продолжает работать, так же вместо строки `if yes_no == 'да' or yes_no == 'Да'`: лучше использовать `if yes_no.lower() =='Да':`, так вы будете переводить строку в нижний регистр, а в вашем случае ваша программа не сработает на 'ДА' или 'Да', это не критично но вы сами сказали что примите критику).

```
import random
import sys
balance = 100

running = True
while running:
    print('Ваш баланс:', balance, 'очков. \nВведите вашу ставку:')

    stavka = int(input())

    def no_funds(balance):
        global stavka
        stavka = int(input())
        if stavka <= balance:
            print('Ваша ставка: ', str(stavka), 'очков(а)')
        else:
            print('Недостаточно средств')
            print('Введите корректное число:')
            no_funds(balance)

    if stavka <= balance:
        print('Ваша ставка:', str(stavka), 'очков(а)')
    else:
        print('Недостаточно средств')
        print('Введите корректное число:')
        no_funds(balance)


    a = random.randint(1, 3) % 2

    choice = input('Что выпадет: Орёл (введите "1") или Решка (введите"2")?\n')

    if choice == 1: #если выпал орёл
        if a == 1:
            print('Выпал Орёл, Вы выиграли!')
            balance = balance + stavka
        else:
            print('Выпала Решка, Вы проиграли!')
            balance = balance - stavka
    else:
        if a == 0:
            print('Выпала Решка, Вы выиграли!')
            balance = balance + stavka
        else:
            print('Выпал Орёл, Вы проиграли!')
            balance = balance - stavka

    print('Ваш новый баланс:', balance, 'очков')

    if balance == 1000:
        print('Ты абсолютный победитель, нет смысла играть дальше!')
        sys.exit()
    if balance<=0:
        print('Вы проиграли, но не расстраивайтесь в следующий раз повезет')
        running=False

    yes_no = input('Сыграть снова?\n')

    if yes_no.lower() == 'да':
        running = True
    else:
        print('Хорошо поиграли. Увидимся!')
        running = False
```

Но насколько я знаю  использовать global и nonlocal плохая практика, подробнее:https://tirinox.ru/global-nonlocal/
Вот как можно реализовать без глобализации переменной:

```
import random
import sys
balance = 100

running = True

while running:
    print('Ваш баланс:', balance, 'очков. \nВведите вашу ставку:')
    stavka = int(input())
    if stavka <= balance:
        print('Ваша ставка: ', str(stavka), 'очков(а)')

    else:
        print('Недостаточно средств')
        print('Введите корректное число:')
        continue
             
    def choice(stavka,balance):
        a = random.randint(1, 3) % 2

        choice = input('Что выпадет: Орёл (введите "1") или Решка (введите"2")?\n')
        if choice == 1: 
            if a == 0:
                print('Выпала Решка, Вы выиграли!')
                balance = balance + stavka
                return balance
            else:
                print('Выпал Орёл, Вы проиграли!')
                balance = balance - stavka
                return balance
        else:  #если выпал орёл
            if a == 1:
                print('Выпал Орёл, Вы выиграли!')
                balance = balance + stavka
                return balance
            else:
                print('Выпала Решка, Вы проиграли!')
                balance = balance - stavka
                return balance
    balance =choice(stavka,balance)
    if balance == 1000:
        print('Ты абсолютный победитель, нет смысла играть дальше!')
        sys.exit()
    if balance<=0:
        print('Вы проиграли, но не расстраивайтесь в следующий раз повезет')
        sys.exit()
    yes_no = input('Сыграть снова?\n')
    if yes_no.lower() == 'да':
        continue
    else:
        print('Хорошо поиграли. Увидимся!')
        sys.exit()
```

Также корректнее будет использовать не `running==True`, а `continue`(начинает следующий проход цикла, минуя оставшееся тело цикла (for или while)), ну и так же зачем вы используете библиотеку random2, если в python есть просто random,правильно еще будет в функцию `no_funds` передавать используемое значение.
PS.надеюсь объяснил все четко и ясно(это мой первый ответ на вопрос :D)

Comment: Читайте ответ ниже, я написал, что это плохой метод( я про использование global), так же я хотел бы узнать чему я еще плохому научил, этот уже вопрос для себя, чтобы так не делать, так же отредактировать вопрос